# append div with additional functon

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an odd task. I am simply trying to add an additonal function on an element when its clicked. I cant seem to trigger the addScroll function that is found within my methods. As you can see, the div should be appended to the screen when the button is clicked. Once that div is clicked as well, the remove method is applied and I also want to apply the addScrollBack().

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    chocs: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  addScrollBack: function(){
  alert("test");
  },
handlePosterClick: function(choc){
alert("ckciked")

     window.top.$(".2l-body").css("overflow","hidden");
    
$("#cook").append(`<div style="background-color:blue;height:200px; width:300px" onclick="document.querySelector('#popover-div').remove();addScrollBack();>test</div>`);
   
   },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="cook">

  </div>
  <button v-on:click="handlePosterClick(choc)">
        Book
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not using a MVC approach ? Your div are stored in a list of data objects (or even just as a count of divs to render if you don't need data...), then render it using a `v-for` over that list (or over the range of divs to display) ? This way, it would be much simpler, and avoid manual dom manipulation, and let vue do the hard stuff with even better performances...

Comment: Also, since you are begining with vue, maybe you should start with vue 3.x ? (and for your question, your function may not be called because you are manipulating the dom yourself and your function call is not bound the the component method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this :

https://codepen.io/hl037/pen/QWOjwyK

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  {{displayDiv}}
  <div id="cook">
    <div
      v-if="displayDiv"
      style="background-color:blue;height:200px; width:300px"
      v-on:click="onDivClicked"
    >
      test
    </div>
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="displayDiv=true">
    Book
  </button>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    displayDiv:false,
    chocs: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    onDivClicked(){
      /*document.querySelector('#popoverdiv').remove();*/
      this.addScrollBack();
    },
    addScrollBack: function(){
      alert("test");
    },
    handlePosterClick: function(choc){
    },
  }
})
```

...Instead of manipulating the dom yourself, just use vue's template, with a model controlling its behavior. The same applies to your other component (the popup) : it should instead listen on a custom event on this component to add/remove scroll using reactivity.

Using vanilla javascript for dom modification, event-handling etc. is NOT recommended with vue. Always use vue's way of doing it. vanilla dom modification should only be done by experts, mostly to interface with non-vue code.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, but suggestion is use `v-html` instead of `append`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    cook: "Old content OR blank",
    chocs: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  addScrollBack: function(){
  alert("test");
  },
handlePosterClick: function(choc){

//alert("ckciked " + choc)
// window.top.$(".2l-body").css("overflow","hidden");


// inline Scripting not recommanded,
 this.cook= `<div style="background-color:blue;height:200px; width:300px" >test</div>`;
   
   },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="cook" v-html="cook">
    
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="handlePosterClick('choc')">
        Book
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: so basically when i click the blue box, i want to trigger the addscroll method, which should alert

Comment: I down voted because doing so will necessary end up to really hard to maintain code... And I think whatever the op is trying to do is definitively easier using the the component template with `v-for` and `v-if` rather than using v-html or changing manually the dom wich should be considered as very last resort ! (I would even say, they should only be considered for compatibility with non-vue components)